# Converting struct to unique_ptr from struct member

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, unique-ptr

So in part of a larger refactoring, I need to assert that a certain struct is_standard_layout because of communication between server client.
Consider the following:

```cpp
struct CommonHeader
{
    uint32_t m1;
    uint32_t headerSize;
};
```

Previously all other headers had derived from this like so:

```cpp
// old style
struct OtherHeaderOld : public CommonHeader
{
    // CommonHeader placed here implicitly with gcc compiler.
    uint32_t m2;
};
```

But this does not guarantee standard_layout. Until now the compilers we've used luckily placed the base as the first member.
For the refactoring I'd like to do this:

```cpp
// new style
struct OtherHeaderNew
{
    CommonHeader header; // placed here instead of inheriting. Same layout as old struct with gcc.
    uint32_t     m2;

    std::unique_ptr<CommonHeader> ToUniqueHeader() 
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<CommonMessageHeader>(&header); 
    }
};
```

So far, this should all be equivalent in layout. However, at some point in the code I need to transfer this header to a `unique_ptr<CommonHeader>`.
Before this was easily done with:

```cpp
// old style header here
auto uOtherPtr = std::make_unique<OtherHeaderOld>();

// do some init code here

// do implicit conversion is no problem 
// since it is derived from CommonHeader
unique_ptr<CommonHeader> uPtr = uOtherPtr;

// send the msg based on the CommonHeader
Dipatch(uPtr);
```

Now, with the new version of the header I'd like to do:

```cpp
// new style header here
auto uOtherPtr = std::make_unique<OtherHeaderNew>();

// do some init code here

// no use of auto here to emphasize the conversion to CommonHeader
// this will compile, but will the UniquePtr clean up the whole object correctly?
unique_ptr<CommonHeader> uPtr = uOtherPtr->ToUniqueHeader();

// send the msg based on the CommonHeader
Dipatch(uPtr);
```

This compiles without a problem.
So finally the question:
Is this a legal way to convert to a unique_ptr?

**Update**
Some people suggested that deleting via the first member was different than deleting the ptr to the object. I tried this with GCC here,
https://godbolt.org/z/vzncsGbGY
And it seems to produce the exact same output (try to switch with DELETE_VIA_FIRST_MEMBER)

**P.S.**
I tried to look at the *documentation*, but couldn't find out the appropriate place to look for the rules underlying this, so any reference will be very welcome.

Comment: Imo your approach violates the use of `unique_ptr` since the returned `unique_ptr` does not own `header` - `header` belongs to the instance of `OtherHeaderNew`

Comment: @Odysseus True, but the address of the OtherHeaderNew and the first member are the same. The question is if the destructor can delete the whole object based on the address alone.

Comment: @SupAI • "*if the destructor can delete the whole object based on the address alone*".  **No**.

Comment: *Until now the compilers we've used luckily placed the base as the first member.* I think that's guaranteed by the Standard (at least, when there's only *one* base class). It's certainly *implied* by this: (13.2, C++17) *A pointer to a derived class can be implicitly converted to a pointer to an accessible unambiguous base class.*

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `ToUniqueHeader()` can just return a raw pointer (or you might like to have it return a reference).  Just make sure that you manage your object lifetimes properly.

Comment: You can't hand over ownership of a member to a `unique_ptr`; the object that it's a member of has exclusive rights to it. (Think about how correct `delete &uOtherPtr->header` would be.)

Comment: @AdrianMole it is not guaranteed to place it there, but it is probably done so by most compilers. See fx https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType. This specifically violates:
**Has all non-static data members and bit-fields declared in the same class (either all in the derived or all in some base)**

Comment: **@Eljay and molbdino**, this was exactly what I wasn't sure of. It could be that the object size / type was saved along with the address, so that it could resolve that when the delete was called on that address. But you state that this is not so. Where in the documentation do you find evidence for this?

Comment: @PaulSanders the whole idea was to hand off the memory management to another part of the system. This would not be accomplished with a **raw pointer**.

Comment: @SupAl Well I think that others are pointing out why this approach is flawed.

Comment: @PaulSanders yes it is. But what are the rules for this? Is it okay to convert the base class to a unique_ptr in the case of the **OtherHeaderOld** and expect it to destroy it without any virtual destructor?

Comment: @SupAl The consensus seems to be 'in theory, no, but in practise, usually yes'.  A virtual destructor might be wise, any reason not to use one?

Comment: @PaulSanders, The thing here is that there is not resource management, so is it really necessary to call a derived destructor?
Also, standard layout do **not allow any virtual functions, ctors or dtors**.

Comment: Regarding your godbolt test: you can't detemine through observation that code *doesn't* have undefined behaviour. `&(d->b)` is a `uint32_t*` that wasn't the result of `new`, and thus passing it to `delete` is undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo, you're right and I was wrong about the godbolt code. There's a small difference between the output :) - I think that answered my question.
**Thanks for the input everyone!**

Comment: @SupAl C++ is not ameanable to the scientific method. You can't just try things and see, because of undefined behaviour.

Comment: OK, I will be more specific: you can't determine the absence of undefined behaviour from either a program's behaviour *or* the generated code - your "trick" would be just as wrong if it generated the same code.